# Installing a build time modified DLL to target machine GAC

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010

I'm using Visual Studio's standard setup. During my solution build process, a DLL is modified and re-signed. I want the modified DLL to be copied to a setup that is also in the same solution so that it is installed on the target machine.  The DLL should end up in the target machine's GAC.

Is there any way to do this in one build process? The DLL is modified each build.

Answer (score 1):

To deploy an assembly to the target computer GAC with Web Setup project, we can drag the assemblies to Global Assembly Cache Folder(Right-click File System on Target Machine, click Add Special Folder, and then click Global Assembly Cache Folder). For more information, see http://support.microsoft.com/kb/324168

We also can try to run some scripts to register assemblies through the Gacutil Tool (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315682) on target machine in Custom Action of Setup Project.

For the Custom Action example, see http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/06/15/tip-trick-creating-packaged-asp-net-setup-programs-with-vs-2005.aspx

Comment: I think I can try using Publish.GacInstall(), the target machine will not have gacutil.exe. However now I'm not sure how to add a build time created DLL to the setup payload so that the target machine will have access to it.

Answer (score 0):

Make the install do two components using the same file.
One as a global assembly, and one as a private assembly.

These links should be helpful:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2005/06/24/432521.aspx

And

http://msitekkie.wordpress.com/2011/02/03/installing-net-assemblies/

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks for the input but I'm not sure how to follow up on the blog posts. I think my question was unclear and hopefully my edit has made it more understandable.

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question now that you have updated it :). It now looks like to me that you need MSBuild and WiX.  I have used WiX more than MSBuild, but they are pretty big subjects.  Hope that helps!!